# Stuttering animation when spanning multiple sprite sheets in easeljs

Tags: javascript, animation, sprite, easeljs

Using EaselJS, I have an animation that the user may scroll through with a custom 
slider.  It uses 10 sprite sheets to display 152 frames of size 1924 x 
1708.

```
//images were declared above in style | var chromophoreAni0 = new 
Image(); | 
var data = { 
            images: [chromophoreAniImage0, chromophoreAniImage1, 
chromophoreAniImage2, chromophoreAniImage3, chromophoreAniImage4, 
                    chromophoreAniImage5, chromophoreAniImage6, 
chromophoreAniImage7, chromophoreAniImage8, chromophoreAniImage9], 
            frames: {count: 152, width: 356, height: 316}, 
            animations: {all: [0, 151]} 
        }; 
chromophoreSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheet(data); 
chromophoreAni = new BitmapAnimation(chromophoreSpriteSheet); 
chromophoreAni.gotoAndStop(1); 
stage.addChild(chromophoreAni); 
stage.update(); 
//whenever the slider changes position | 
gotoAndStop(currentSliderFrame) |
```

The animation works but there is a very noticeable hiccup whenever the 
animation is hopping between sprite sheets.  Since the user can go 
from one end of the slider to the other as fast as they want, it may 
be that the animation is being played to fast for the images to keep 
up.  However, the animation was only acceptably smooth when scrolling 
at a snail's pace.  It also occurred to me that the sprite sheet size 
of 1424 x 1708 might be too large to load at such a high speed.  So I 
decreased the image sizes to as low as 1424 x 632 (<250kb) and while 
there was improvement, the lag was still there.  If there is a more 
optimal method to do this, I haven't seen it.  Any input into this 
scenario would be wonderful.  The ultimate goal for this is to run smoothly on the ipad, so any image size larger than 2048 x 2048 won't fly.

Is it possible that I could get greater performance using css sprites or my own custom methods in javascript?

Comment: I would be curious to see if appmobi's directcanvas (https://github.com/appMobi/ios) on a mobile device helps.

Comment: I'm having a potentially similar problem with SpriteSheetUtils.addReversedFrames() - thread is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993558/easeljs-bitmapanimation-gotoandplay-lag/14127093#14127093

Comment: I still haven't found an excellent way of animating smoothly between large sprite sheets, even after dropping EaselJS and making a strictly animation object.  I wound up dropping sprite sheets in favor of image sequences if an animation will not fit on a single sheet.  Pre-caching an image sequence before animation had perfectly smooth results on all browsers for iOS; even for large, hi-res images.